# Git and symlinks

Tags: git

I have 2 issues:

1. I want git to ignore symlinks
2. I have noticed late that it is committing symlinks.  HOw can i remove these committed symlinks.  They have already been pushed to a remote.

Answer (score 15):

add all symbolic links in `.gitignore`

```
find . -type l >> .gitignore
```

remove all symbolic links from repository

```
find . -type l -exec git rm --cached {} \;
```

Comment: This solved the problem for me. I had already tried the first line, but the second was the one that did it.

Answer (score 1):

1) Don't `git add` any symlinks then. That includes things like `git add -A` and what-not that automatically add things that aren't currently being tracked.

2) `git rm <symlink>`; repeat for each symlink, then `git commit`. Of course you'll need to do this on every branch. Also, if you want to remove all symlinks throughout your project's history, you'll need to do the same on every commit, which can be done with `git filter-branch`.

Comment: Also, add any symlinks into `.gitignore`.